# Multiple MySQL clients connecting to 1 MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, architecture, cloud

MySQL server is set up at 192.168.1.101.

The MySQL client is set up at 192.168.1.200.  The database user `joe` is granted permission to access `my_db` via the SQL query

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON 'my_db'.'*' TO 'joe'@'192.168.1.200' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' REQUIRE SSL;
```

When additional client servers are added, Joe requires a new SQL query with the new IP address.  How can I avoid all these GRANT statements with varying IP addresses?

Machines can constantly be added & removed.  It seems like a nightmare to manage the user rights correctly.

Also, any recommended readings on separating MySQL in cloud applications would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`GRANT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/grant.html):

> #### Account Names and Passwords
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example, `user_name@'%.example.com'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `example.com` domain, and `user_name@'192.168.1.%'` applies to *`user_name`* for any host in the `192.168.1` class C subnet.